# Issue with copy text in react

Tags: reactjs

js and now I am trying to copy my input value text to my clipboard.
I write some code but it not working, please help me figure out and correct my code.

```
      import InputBox from "./Input"
      import ButtonBox from "./Button"

      const EarlyAccessLimitation = () => {
      let urlAddress = window.location;

      function copyURLToClipboard() {
        const UrlText = urlAddress;
        UrlText.select();
        alert.execCommand("copy");
      }
      return (

        <div>
             <InputBox url={urlAddress} />
             <ButtonBox onClick={copyURLToClipboard}/>
       </div>
      );
    };

    export default  EarlyAccessLimitation ;
```

It not show any error, but also it not copy the text.

Comment: You seem to be trying to call `.select()` on a string. The string has to be part of the DOM for this method to work, and you need to select the element. This answer covers pretty much all aspects of JS clipboard control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I was very grateful if you show me how can I modify my code, thanks

Answer (score -1):

This component allows users to easily copy an invitation link with a single click, making it super convenient for sharing referral links or any other important information. The button updates its state dynamically to let users know when the content has been successfully copied.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourReactComponent = () => {
  const [invitationCode] = useState('http://client.gicmarkets.com/register?ref_id=5003');
  const [copyText, setCopyText] = useState('Copy to invite');

  const copyCode = async () => {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(invitationCode);
    setCopyText('Copied');
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setCopyText('Copy to invite');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Your Translation Function for IbLink`}</p>
      <p className="copy-link text-truncate">
        http://client.gicmarkets.com/register?ref_id=5003
      </p>
      <span onClick={copyCode} onMouseOut={reset} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        <button className="ma-0 ml-2 text-capitalize btn-account" onClick={copyCode}>
          <i className="anticon anticon-copy" style={{ marginRight: '4px' }}></i>
          <b>{`Your Translation Function for copy`}</b>
        </button>
      </span>
      <span>{copyText}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourReactComponent;
```

Feel free to tailor the description based on your specific context and any additional details you'd like to emphasize.